# Excel: Filter subcategories

Tags: excel, filter, categories

In a table, is it possible to create subcategories to filter like you can [do with dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrOzm.png) (Year > Month > Date)

Comment: Just a table that you can filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes........the usual technique is to add one or more "helper" columns to contain the criteria you need for the filter.